# Convert char array to Opencv Mat

Tags: opencv, char, mat

I have defined an array char buf[], and need to convert it into Opencv Mat. Is there a way?

```
char buf[Max_size];
```

Comment: it would be better if you  give some details. Why you want this? what is the data? where you are going to use the output cv::Mat

Comment: In my server, I am receiving an image in bytes from a client and store them in array of char buf[]. then I want to send buf[] to be processed by a function SURF which only accepts Mat variable. In the solution you provided, do I have to put that line inside a for loop?

Comment: No you do not need to put it in a loop

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing that called: "Converting `char` array to `cv::Mat`". `cv::Mat` is a container that represents an image in the memory. It may own the data and may not. If you want to create a `cv::Mat` to represent an image that its bitmap data in some `char` array, you may use the following code. This is assuming that you know the rows and the columns of the image.

```
cv::Mat my_mat(rows,cols,CV_8UC1,&buf[0]); //in case of BGR image use CV_8UC3
```

Keep in mind that `cv::Mat` in this case does not hold the ownership of the data. You have delete your data manually. However, since it is a stack array, you do not need to anything.

Comment: For anyone else googling; if your data is `unsigned char*`, you need to cast to `void*` in the constructor call for the overload resolution to find the proper constructor.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Humams's answer is correct, however, here is a complete C++ example on how to get an image from an unsigned char array.

```
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>  

    unsigned char img_data[] = {
        // first row, 4 colored pixels
        0, 0, 0,
        255, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0 ,
        0, 255, 0,

        // second row, 4 colored pixels
        0, 0, 255,
        0, 0, 0,
        255, 0, 255,
        0, 0, 0
    };

    // get a correct pointer to the data
    unsigned char * img_data_ptr = (unsigned char*) &img_data;

    cv::Mat img(2, 4, CV_8UC3, img_data_ptr);
    cv::cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    cv::imwrite("/out/myimage.png", img);
```

The example is dockerized at https://github.com/FilipSivak/opencv-minimal